# redis: consume elements from zset from several service instances

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I've an zset on my redis filled with several elements.

By other hand, I have **several service instances** need to "consume" those elements.

When I say consume, I mean, each instance:

1. Get the first element from zset
2. I process it
3. If everything has been **FINE**, remove it from zset

Problems here:

- two instances could proces the same element twice due to race conditions.

By other hand, I could pop first element:

1. Pop me the first element from zset
2. I process it
3. If something has been **WRONG**, push it again

Problems here:

- If process stops at step `2.`, the element is lost forever since it's not added at zset again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at Redis Streams, with Consumer Groups it is ideal for avoiding race conditions and managing failures. https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro

Answer (score 0):

you have several options

- do it yourself, then you need to manage the state of the jobs in the zset

  - states: active / failed / completed  ...
  - on fail => emit error event to push it back to queue
  - on completed => emit complete event so that we can safely remove it from the queue
  - retry ? retry delay ?
  - lock duration?
  - etc...
- OR if you want to stick with redis? find a queue lib built on top of redis. those kind of libs can do all the above for you and better tested.
- OR if you're using a recent version of redis, you may want to take a look into disque (https://github.com/antirez/disque-module). This module is from redis author himself.
- OR use other proper queue solution